# Как записать хранимую процедуру через C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net

Есть несколько файлов каждый из который содержит создание ХП.
Необходимо реализовать алгоритм при котором программа запускаясь ищет в БД ХП по имени и если нет то создает их.

Можно, конечно, включить файлы с ХП в проект, в USE подставлять имя БД из конфига и 
 предварительно искать эти файлы в папке с программой. Но есть ли другой, более изящный способ, создавать ХП на сервере ?

Comment: А как же миграции? В коде останется лишь вызывать по названию и передать параметры

Comment: @SultanovShamil Вы имеете в виду `DbMigration().CreateStoredProcedure()` ?

Comment: Можно так, можно из sql файлов импортировать запрос создания и запускать в миграции

Comment: Если совсем "в лоб", без наворотов из EF, то в скрипты создания хранимок можно включить код проверки наличия хранимки перед ее созданием [тут есть несколько вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072174/5796587)